# Openstack VM (redhat as well) is sending strange DNS queries

Tags: domain-name-system, openstack

I have some strange DNS queries and I cannot find why or which process is asking for something like that.

Under strange I mean request for "-P". It seems, system has some kind of ghost "feature" which is sending "-P" requests.

Checked in /var/log/messages and all other logs, but nothing.

It looks like this:

```
750 4.880197       172.34.167.129        172.34.167.193        DNS      64     Standard query 0xa6d9 A -P
751 4.880228       172.34.167.129        172.34.167.193        DNS      64     Standard query 0xcf06 AAAA -P
752 4.882101       172.34.167.193        172.34.167.129        DNS      64     Standard query response 0xa6d9 Refused A -P
753 4.882122       172.34.167.193        172.34.167.129        DNS      64     Standard query response 0xcf06 Refused AAAA -P
```

Details:

```
No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    750 4.880197       172.34.167.129        172.34.167.193        DNS      64     Standard query 0xa6d9 A -P

Frame 750: 64 bytes on wire (512 bits), 64 bytes captured (512 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.34.167.129, Dst: 172.34.167.193
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 27798, Dst Port: 53
Domain Name System (query)
    [Response In: 752]
    Transaction ID: 0xa6d9
    Flags: 0x0100 Standard query
    Questions: 1
    Answer RRs: 0
    Authority RRs: 0
    Additional RRs: 0
    Queries
        -P: type A, class IN
            Name: -P
            [Name Length: 2]
            [Label Count: 1]
            Type: A (Host Address) (1)
            Class: IN (0x0001)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    751 4.880228       172.34.167.129        172.34.167.193        DNS      64     Standard query 0xcf06 AAAA -P

Frame 751: 64 bytes on wire (512 bits), 64 bytes captured (512 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.34.167.129, Dst: 172.34.167.193
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 27798, Dst Port: 53
Domain Name System (query)
    [Response In: 753]
    Transaction ID: 0xcf06
    Flags: 0x0100 Standard query
    Questions: 1
    Answer RRs: 0
    Authority RRs: 0
    Additional RRs: 0
    Queries
        -P: type AAAA, class IN
            Name: -P
            [Name Length: 2]
            [Label Count: 1]
            Type: AAAA (IPv6 Address) (28)
            Class: IN (0x0001)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    752 4.882101       172.34.167.193        172.34.167.129        DNS      64     Standard query response 0xa6d9 Refused A -P

Frame 752: 64 bytes on wire (512 bits), 64 bytes captured (512 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.34.167.193, Dst: 172.34.167.129
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 53, Dst Port: 27798
Domain Name System (response)
    [Request In: 750]
    [Time: 0.001904000 seconds]
    Transaction ID: 0xa6d9
    Flags: 0x8105 Standard query response, Refused
    Questions: 1
    Answer RRs: 0
    Authority RRs: 0
    Additional RRs: 0
    Queries
        -P: type A, class IN
            Name: -P
            [Name Length: 2]
            [Label Count: 1]
            Type: A (Host Address) (1)
            Class: IN (0x0001)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    753 4.882122       172.34.167.193        172.34.167.129        DNS      64     Standard query response 0xcf06 Refused AAAA -P

Frame 753: 64 bytes on wire (512 bits), 64 bytes captured (512 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.34.167.193, Dst: 172.34.167.129
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 53, Dst Port: 27798
Domain Name System (response)
    [Request In: 751]
    [Time: 0.001894000 seconds]
    Transaction ID: 0xcf06
    Flags: 0x8105 Standard query response, Refused
    Questions: 1
    Answer RRs: 0
    Authority RRs: 0
    Additional RRs: 0
    Queries
        -P: type AAAA, class IN
            Name: -P
            [Name Length: 2]
            [Label Count: 1]
            Type: AAAA (IPv6 Address) (28)
            Class: IN (0x0001)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would assume that such is the result of a simple misconfiguration  where a hostname variable is expected but missing and the next command line option, `-P`, gets interpreted as the hostname parameter.

Something like this:

```
HOST=""
PORT=""
/path/to/command $OTHER_ARGS -H $HOST -P $PORT
```

which due to empty and missing variables looks like:

```
/path/to/command -H -P
```

Finding which application that is, that might be as simple or as difficult as finding the application (that fails to run correctly) that supports a `-P` commandline switch ...

Comment: thx, i found it. in syslog config :( /etc/rsyslog.d/eventFrwd.conf:if $fromhost-ip == '127.0.0.1' and $syslogtag contains 'tspevents' then @@[-P]:6514;LOGRFC5424